# Amuzaj vortoj kaj frazoj en Esperanto

Tags: word-formation, idiom

Mi volas ekkoni pli da amuzaj vortoj kaj frazoj en Esperanto. Ekz.:

- “germanujo” estas ujo por Germanoj ktp. (kia amuza bildo – granda ujo, plena de germanoj)
- “langrompilo” (tongue twister) estas laŭvorte ilo por rompi sian langon
- "malgraŭ" devenas de la itala vorto “malgrado”, sed “malgraŭ” aspektas kiel la malo de “graŭ”. Tial, kelkaj homoj nun uzas “graŭ” kvazaŭ la malo de “malgraŭ”
- “Ĝi estas laŭ mi volapukaĵo” signifas ke oni tute ne komprenas ion. Estas amuze ke Esperanto uzas Volapük, alia fama artefarita lingvo, kvazaŭ ekzemplo por nekompreneblaĵo.

Mia demando estas: Kiujn aliajn amuzajn vortojn kaj frazojn vi konas?

Mi scias ke “amuza” estas nepreciza vorto. Precipe, mi serĉas vortojn kaj frazojn kiuj – kiel la superaj ekzemploj – kreas strangan imagon en menso, aŭ kiuj havas strangan devonon aŭ uzas vortojn en nekutiman metaforan sencon.

Comment: Saluton, ĉu vi povus precizigi vian demandon? Se ne, la demando verŝajne estos fermita. Ankaŭ, tio kio estas "amuza" dependas de la alparolanto, kaj tio ankaŭ estas kialo por fermi demandon. Bonvolu konsulti la diversajn kialojn fermi demandon per klako sur "close" sub demando: -- Ekzemple:

Why should this question be closed? Too broad: "There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs."

Comment: Dankon. Mi pensis ke tio povus esti problemo. Kapti la sencon de “amuza” estas malfacile. Tamen mi pensas ke ĝi estas interesa demando. Mi nun provis plibonigi kaj klarigi mian demandon.

Comment: Estas interesa demando, sed mi ankaux pensas ke estas "too broad". Ni bezonas "criteria" for selecting the best answer. Tio ne eblas kun la demando tiel.

Answer (score 5):

Iu kreis (per komputila programo) liston da 2809 kalemburoj. Vidu ĝin [ĉi tie](http://pastebin.com/P3E7id8w). Multe da tiuj eble estas amuzaj (kompreneble mi ne legis ĉiujn).

*Noto:* Mi unuafoje eksciis pri tio de [ĉi tie](https://www.reddit.com/r/Esperanto/comments/54cjcy/mi_faris_2809_kalemburojn/?st=itnzktox&sh=19d84809). Do, la afiŝinto estas la kreinto de la listo.

Comment: Dankon! Mi ankaŭ jus trovis “sen-teme”/“sent-eme” kaj “literaturo = litera turo”.

Answer (score 4):

Ekzistas tiom multe - amasojn - da amuzaj vortoj en Esperanto!

Dolchamar estas amuza (la muzikgrupo).
Mi trovis tiun vorton: "*fi-kant-aro*" /"*fik-ant-aro*"...

Mi ege ŝatas "La kata strofo estas katastrofo."

Kukurbo estas amuza vorto por mi…

Mi ŝatas kion [Raymond Schwarz](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raymond_Schwartz) faris en la lingvo. Nepre legu lin! :-)

Mi ege ŝatas vortojn kun -*um*-, ĉar estas tiom nespezifa kaj oni povas fari kelkajn kombinaciojn kiel: *kunumi*, *mojosumi*

Kaj kio estas *kunumulo*?

Por mi, "fanfari" pentras tre taŭgan bildon en mia kapo.

Comment: Dankon! Sed bonvolu klarigi al mi, kio estas "fik-ant-aro"? Kio estas "ant-"?

Comment: @ManuelEberl *X-anto* estas iu aŭ io, kiu X-as. Do, fik-anto estas iu, kiu fikas. Kaj fik-ant-aro estas aro de tiuj, kiuj fikas. Simile, *X-onto* estas io aŭ iu kiu X-os, kaj *X-into* estas io aŭ iu kiu X-is.

Comment: Ah, nature. Mi stultis! Mi legis ĝin elparolate ‘fik-antaro’, do mi ne komprenis ke la ‘ant’ estas la afikso ‘-ant-’ (mi pensis ke ĝi estas devenata de eble vorto ‘anto’ aŭ ‘anti’). Dankon por la klarigo!