# How many Esperanto pun words are there?

Tags: culture

There are some words I know:

1. kolego (kol-eg-o) as in "-Kial ĝirafo neniam estas sola? -Ĉar ĝi
   havas kolegon."
2. laŭtema (laŭ-tema aŭ laŭt-em-a)
3. trafike (e-vorto devenas el trafiko aŭ tra-fike) as in Claude
   Piron's sex crime fantasy "ĉu ŝi mortu trafike?"

Do you know any other pun words?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Amuzaj vortoj kaj frazoj en Esperanto](http://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/1001/amuzaj-vortoj-kaj-frazoj-en-esperanto)

Comment: @LyubomirVasilev Not all puns are funny and not all funny things are puns, so I don't consider it as a duplicate.

Answer (score 9):

[Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20030822073345id_/www.cix.co.uk/~morven/lang/esp_appx.html#appx2) is a pretty long list of puns.

By the way, I don't agree with the author of that website that the existence of such ambiguities is a big problem. It just shows that Esperanto is a living language, and not just a theoretical construct made by Zamenhof. When people start using a language in real life, new words and constructions come up naturally, and some ambiguities are bound to arise.

**Edit**: I just happened to discover one more pun: *dialekto* ‘dialect’ or ‘divine sofa’.

Comment: I like the topical _kukurbo_: 'pumpkin' or 'city of cakes' :)

Comment: It's more fun that way; the band Persone makes use of these puns and wordplays quite a bit, one example being the band name itself (person-e; per-son-e). If you want a language where every word can be parsed in only one way, that's what Lojban is for (well, one of the things it's for).

Answer (score 7):

I think Esperanto has so many pun words that it’s impossible to list them all! :-) I keep discovering new puns all the time… Okay, a few more for your list:

- kulmino: kulmino aŭ mino de kuloj :-)
- elokventa: elokventa (eloquent) aŭ ”venanta el ok ventoj”
- heroino: heroino (the drug) aŭ ina heroo
- sentema: sen-tema aŭ sent-ema :-)
- ĉiele: ĉielmaniere aŭ en la ĉielo
  ktp.

Comment: New puns keep entering Esperanto all the time – here’s a fresh example: Some _programistoj_ have started to use the word **apo** for **aplikaĵo** (just like the English _app_, look for instance at [the amikumu webpage](https://www.amikumu.com) ). Great! Now we can make lots of new puns:

Comment: • apoteko : medicinvendejo aŭ teko por apoj…

Comment: • apaĉo : ano de la apaĉa popolo aŭ malbona apo…

Comment: ktp. Isn’t Esperanto a great living language? :-)

Comment: One of the best, that hasn't been mentioned yet, is intimo/in-timo.

Answer (score 5):

There is a limitless number of puns in Esperanto.

The reason is that we can introduce new roots in Esperanto ([see the rule 15 of the Fundamento](http://www.akademio-de-esperanto.org/fundamento/gramatiko_angla.html)). So every new root that is long enough can be read as a combination of others old roots ([see the rule 11](http://www.akademio-de-esperanto.org/fundamento/gramatiko_angla.html)). Also, every old root can be seen as a combination of newer roots. And almost everything in Esperanto is a root.

One exemple is *vegetaran-o*, which can be read as "*v-eg-et-ar-an-o*", which is *a member of a group of small big Vs*, which is maybe just the letter V.

"Do you know any othen pun words?" Yes, I know many, too many. There are some people in Twitter who often post bad puns.

Answer (score 1):

Krokodilo - Ilo per kio oni krokodas

Malajzio - La malo de Ajzio

Comment: Kio estas krokodi?

Answer (score 1):

Finfine Finn' Finne deklamis: *"Pro vi, ho nova vin', ni dek lamis."*

Answer (score 0):

*Banano* - Banana or member of the bath?

Answer (score 0):

[Gijom' Armide](http://jadeo.net/) has a song [Eĉ se ne amen](http://jadeo.net/index.php/auskulti/ec-se-ne-amen/) in which he first sings nesentemo (lack of feeling) and later he sings ne sen temo (not without a theme); of course, in writing it is not identical because of the spaces, but it works in speaking or, as the case may be, in singing.

Answer (score 0):

"La stranga butiko" de R. Schwartz = last' ranga butiko (https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_stranga_butiko)

Answer (score 0):

Trovis mi la vorton **gejsero**, kiu pli ofte volas diri *geyser* ol diri *gay serum*.

Answer (score -1):

kasisto - tenanto de mono

kaŝisto - ankaŭ tenanto de mono